# P/Invoke call when debugging closes app, but not from compiled exe

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am trying to do a P/Invoke call to a Python CFFI library. The application crashes when the P/Invoke call gets made when I'm debugging in Visual Studio.

However, when the application is executed outside of Visual Studio (i.e. from CMD), the application does not crash, and returns the expected results from the CFFI library.

I am using an embedded version of Python install (3.8.10 x64)

My code is as follows:

```
public static class External
{
    [DllImport("cffi.dll",EntryPoint = "auth", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern IntPtr auth(string apiKey, bool discover);

  
    public static async Task<dynamic> Auth(string apiKey, bool discover)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await Task.Run(() => auth(apiKey, discover)); << This line crashes the application when debugging in VS. No obvious errors are displayed or Exceptions thrown

            if (response == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new NullReferenceException("Error -> auth() -> NULL response detected");

            string responseString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(response);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var a = ex;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Program Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", @"D:\04022021 Backup\sling.io\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\py", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", @"D:\04022021 Backup\sling.io\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\py", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Console.WriteLine("Authed");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var res = await External.Auth("xxxxx", false);
    }

    static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
        Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Runtime terminating: {0}", args.IsTerminating);
    }
```

Things that I have tried/checked:

- The embedded Python in the `PATH` variable is x64
- The Platform Target in VS is x64
- The CFFI DLL is x64
- Running in Release mode within VS **does not** crash the application

Here is a screenshot of the application working outside of Visual Studio:
[image]

Why does the P/Invoke call to `auth` crash my application when I'm debugging in VS? There are no unhandled exceptions caught, and there are no exceptions returned from the CFFI library.

UPDATE:

The Python `auth` function is defined as:

```
def responseWrapper(payload):
    sessionID = payload['sessionID']
    response = ffi.new(
        'char []',
         json.dumps(payload).encode()
    )

    sessions[sessionID].memory_stack = response # hackery to hold memory from gc

    return response



    def getString(payload):
        return ffi.string(payload).decode()
    
    @ffi.def_extern()
    def auth(apiKey, discover):
        api.auth(getString(apiKey), discover=discover)
    
        return responseWrapper({
            'sessionID': 0,
            'response': 'authenticated'
        })
```

UPDATE:

FFI Builder code:

```
ffibuilder = cffi.FFI()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

ffibuilder.embedding_api(
    """
    char *auth(char apiKey[], int discover);
    """
)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

libraryPath = sysconfig.get_config_vars('LIBDIR')
if libraryPath and libraryPath[0]:
    ffibuilder.set_source("cffi", "", library_dirs=libraryPath)
else:
    ffibuilder.set_source("cffi", "")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

with open('template.tpl', 'r') as code:
    ffibuilder.embedding_init_code(code.read())

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

ffibuilder.compile(
    target=f"../cffi.{extensionMap[platform.system()]}",
    verbose=True
)
```

Comment: What is the full Python function declaration? Python strings are Unicode so you need `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` and instead of messing around with `Marshal.PtrToStringUnicode` you should just declare it as `string auth(...`. Side point: `MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is just wrong, instead use `static Task Main(string[] args) {...` and `await MainAsync();`

Comment: @Charlieface updated my question with the Python function definition

Comment: What's your `ffibuilder.cdef` builder script as I think that will contain your `extern` definition

Comment: Updated again with ffi builder code

Comment: perhaps a stupid question, but are you running VS with elevated rights (as admin)?

Comment: I am yes, I've also tried in Jetbrains Rider for what it's worth. Same behavior is observed

Comment: Have you also looked into the Windows EventViewer for possible error messages?